# Automatic connection by ssh to the server at startup

Tags: linux, boot, ssh, debian, auto-login

I would like to know if it's possible to establish a connection to a server via ssh when starting a machine (I configured SSH key based secure authentication).

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What exactly do you mean by "establish a connection to a server via ssh when starting a machine"? Do you mean you want to have a terminal session open that connects via ssh to the server after starting the client?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to try to make clear. Sorry I lack computer science vocabulary.

Comment: The question's tags are suggesting you're running a Debian distribution, which one exactly? That may help some people to target their answer more specifically to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of ssh connection and what you ultimately want to do with it.

Mount sshfs: https://serverfault.com/questions/9605/how-do-i-mount-sshfs-at-boot

Open a terminal when you log in to your desktop: add `xterm -e ssh user@hostname` or some equivalent to your desktop's startup applications

Connect via ssh when you log into the console: A terrible idea as you'd need to carefully craft escape clauses to NOT automatically ssh. Create a `~/.ssh/config` file with the [relevant details](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) and then run `ssh hostAlias`